# How to Copy from Label to TextBox inside GridView

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I've `c# .Net Gridview`, when I try to copy a value from Label cell to TextBox cell in `Gridview`, the TextBox cell change to Label !

In `_RowCommand` :

```
row.Cells[2].Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

`row.Cells[2].Text` changed after assignment from TextBox to Label !

Any idea of reason and solution ?

Remarks: I added code for more explanation.

.aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Names" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Num" 
                OnRowDataBound="GridView_Names_RowDataBound"
                OnRowCommand="GridView_Names_RowCommand"
                AllowPaging="false"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Num" >
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name1" >
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Name2" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Google" Visible="false" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button_Copy" 
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
                                CommandName="OnClickButton_Copy" runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns></asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void GridView_Names_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text; // Cells[2] changes from TextBox to Label !!!
    }
}
protected void GridView_Names_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "OnClickButton_Copy")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow row = GridView_Names.Rows[index];
        GridView_Names.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = row.Cells[1].Text; // Cells[2] changes from TextBox to Label !!!
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's going on? Step by step of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added code for more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have to find the TextBox in Gridview using this command (TextBox)row.FindControl("Name"):

```
protected void GridView_Names_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "OnClickButton_Copy")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    GridViewRow row = GridView_Names.Rows[index];
    //GridView_Names.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = row.Cells[1].Text; // Cells[2] changes from TextBox to Label !!!
        TextBox txtName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Name");
        txtName.Text= row.Cells[3].Text;

}
```